# Kendo UI sortable grid using template column inside AJAX based tab strip

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to find some help in various places for an issue that I'm having with a Kendo UI grid.

### What I'm trying to do

What I'm trying to do is use a server bound grid that uses templates for 2 of its rows inside of a tab strip that I would like to get loaded using "LoadContentFrom" to take advantage of on demand loading.  In addition to that, I need to implement sorting on the grid.

### What I've already tried

I have tried numerous ways to make this happen but have not had any success.  To temporarily solve this problem, I am using the "Content" function to load the data in my tab strips.  The down side of this is that all the data in all my tab strips gets loaded on page load.  This causes the page to load slower and each time I click on a column header to sort, the page refreshes.

### Summary question

So my question is, is it possible to have a tab strip that uses the "LoadContentFrom" method and have a server bound grid within one of the tab strips that can sort?

If it is possible, can someone give me an example of what that would look like?

### My development environment

I am work on an MVC 4 based project.  I am using VB.NET as my programming language.  I am fine with someone providing an answer using C#.

### What my code looks like now

Below is an example of the code that I have now.

#### Tab strip code

```
`@Imports CommericalPortal.BusinessData.Entities
@Imports CommericalPortal.Web.Models.Entities
@imports CommericalPortal.Web.My.Resources
@ModelType Customer

@Code
    ViewBag.Settings.PageTitle = Model.OperatingName

    Dim lastSavedTabIndex As Integer
    If Request.Cookies("TabCustomersPolicySavedIndex") IsNot Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(Request.Cookies("TabCustomersPolicySavedIndex").Value) Then
        lastSavedTabIndex = CInt(Request.Cookies("TabCustomersPolicySavedIndex").Value)
    Else
        lastSavedTabIndex = 1
    End If
End Code

@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip().Name("TabCustomers").SelectedIndex(lastSavedTabIndex) _
    .Items(Sub(actions)
                   actions.Add().Text(TabText.ContactInfoTab).Content(Html.Action("ByLocation", "Contacts", New With {.asPartial = True}).ToHtmlString)
                   actions.Add().Text(TabText.PoliciesTab).Content(Html.Action("ByLocation", "Policies", New With {.asPartial = True}).ToHtmlString)
                   actions.Add().Text(TabText.InvoicesTab).Content(Html.Action("ByLocation", "Invoices", New With {.asPartial = True}).ToHtmlString)
                   actions.Add().Text(TabText.ClaimsTab).Content(Html.Action("ByLocation", "Claims", New With {.asPartial = True}).ToHtmlString)
                   actions.Add().Text(TabText.BillingTab).Content(Html.Action("ForCustomer", "Billing", New With {.asPartial = True}).ToHtmlString)
           End Sub) _
    .Events(Sub(x)
                   x.Select("onSelect")
            End Sub)
    )

<script>
    function onSelect(e) {
        SetupTabStripToRememberActiveTabBetweenPageCalls 
("TabCustomers", "TabCustomersPolicySavedIndex");
    }
</script>`
```

#### Tab strip contents code (grid)

```
`@ModelType ilist(of CommericalPortal.BusinessData.Entities.PACInformation)'
@imports CommericalPortal.Web

@(Html.Kendo.Grid(Model).Name("DisplayPAC") _
    .Columns(Sub(columns)
                 columns.Bound(Function(model) model.AccountNumber).Title(CommericalPortal.BusinessData.Resources.BillingAndInvoices.PacAccountNumberLabel_ShortForm).Sortable(False)
                 columns.Bound(Function(model) model.BankNumber).Title(CommericalPortal.BusinessData.Resources.BillingAndInvoices.PacBankNumberLabel_ShortForm)
                 columns.Bound(Function(model) model.TransitNumber).Title(CommericalPortal.BusinessData.Resources.BillingAndInvoices.PacTransitNumberLabel_ShortForm)
                 columns.Bound(Function(model) model).Template(Function(obj) String.Format("<a href='{0}/{1}'>{2}</a>", Url.Content("~/PAC/Edit"), obj.ID, CommericalPortal.Web.My.Resources.GridText.EditLinkText)).Title("")
                 columns.Bound(Function(model) model).Template(Function(obj) String.Format("<a  href='{0}/{1}'>{2}</a>", Url.Content("~/PAC/ViewCheques"), obj.ID, CommericalPortal.Web.My.Resources.GridText.ViewChequesLinkText)).Title("")
         End Sub) _
    .Sortable(Function(sorting) sorting.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn).Enabled(True))
)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicely structured question, however I am sorry to say that using Server bound Grid inside a TabStrip that has loaded its content with Ajax is not possible. The Grid should be configured for [Ajax binding](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html).